# Loop object in EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
res.render('account', { ..., items: body.rgDescriptions });
```

It comes from:

```
request({
    url: 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=---&steamids=---',
    json: true
 }, function (error, response, body) { ...
```

But when I try to loop in EJS it gives me that there is not such thing as `forEach`.

```
<% items.forEach(function(item) { %>
 <li>blabla</li>
<% }); %>
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: console the `item`

Comment: Maybe `items` is not defined?

Comment: inside `li` tag , use something like `item.a` . `item` should be an object . Use dot(`.`) to access the value .

Comment: `items` is not an array

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Please don't add info to OP question based on your personal assumptions.

Comment: With <%- JSON.stringify(items) %> it showing what I need but only that. If I try for/foreach nothing happens. It's getting out an error "foreach function does not exist".

Comment: @AleksandrM then how we know that item contains value or coming Empty.

Comment: @Khanasyubighi *it showing what I need but only that* - What exactly it is showing?

Comment: @AkhileshSingh What? You've added `item is null.` to OP, but you don't know that.